# Excel VBA add parameters to Max range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA which is working fine

```
Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Data!E3:E7"))
```

This method should be nested in a `FOR` function such as

```
    For i = 3 To j
        Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Data!E3:E5"))
        x = x + 1
    Next
```

How can I parse the `E3` and `E7`to be parameter based according to `i` meaning

```
E3 = "E" + i
E5 = "E" + i + 2
```

full example of what I'm trying:

```
    For i = 3 To j
        Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("Data!E" + i + ":E" + i+2 +"))
        x = x + 1
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sheets("Data").Range("E" & i & ":E" & (i + 2))
```

& is better than + in combining data of various types into a string. Also -- `Range` is a child of `WorkSheet` -- so you need to go through the appropriate `Sheet` object

Comment: @user829174 It should work now. My first attempt concentrated on the concatenation and neglected the sheet complication. The second version had a typo which was fixed. I just tested it in a workbook with a sheet named "Data" and with i = 3 is correctly gave me the max of `Data!E3:E5`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can do this directly without a loop

*As formula*

```
Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 5).Resize(J - 3 + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(Data!R[1]C5:R[" & J - 3 + 1 & "]C5)"
```

*As values*

```
Worksheets(d).Cells(x, 5).Resize(J - 3 + 1, 1).Value = "=MAX(Data!R[1]C5:R[" & J - 3 + 1 & "]C5)"
```